# Using parameter packs to automate dynamic_cast checks

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-dispatch

I'm trying to implement a communication system inside of a GUI. I would like to avoid the visitor pattern for maintainability reasons. Likewise making a dynamic_cast if else statement is not maintainable. The closest I've come is implementing multiple dispatch with tables from Scott Meyers' More Effective C++.

So far I have:

```
SubmitCommand(BaseCommand* pCommand)
{
    m_Distpatcher->Dispatch<DerivedCommand1>(pCommand);
    m_Distpatcher->Dispatch<DerivedCommand2>(pCommand);
    m_Distpatcher->Dispatch<DerivedCommand3>(pCommand);
}
```

Where I would like to be is:

```
SubmitCommand(BaseCommand* pCommand)
{
    m_Distpatcher->Dispatch<DerivedCommand1,
                            DerivedCommand2,
                            DerivedCommand3>(pCommand);
}
```

Where dispatch is a automated way of checking dynamic_cast results for incoming commands.

```
    template<typename K>
    void Dispatch(ICommand* pCommand)
    {
        auto pConcreteCommand = dynamic_cast<K*>(pCommand);
        if (pConcreteCommand)
        {
            //call Recieve on the interface of the owner class
            m_pInstance->Recieve(pConcreteCommand);
        }
    }
```

In this case the specific module would be checked at compile time to make sure it has a function for each argument in the template. Is code block 2 possible?

Comment: Could you share the definition of `Dispatch`?

Comment: Also, what is `DerivedCommand1`?

Comment: Added an edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void Distpatcher::Dispatch(BaseCommand* pCommand)
{
    (DispatchUnique<Ts>(pCommand), ...); // C++17
}
```

so

```
m_Distpatcher->Dispatch<DerivedCommand1,
                        DerivedCommand2,
                        DerivedCommand3>(pCommand);
```

would be equivalent to

```
m_Distpatcher->DispatchUnique<DerivedCommand1>(pCommand);
m_Distpatcher->DispatchUnique<DerivedCommand2>(pCommand);
m_Distpatcher->DispatchUnique<DerivedCommand3>(pCommand);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. What is the operation associated with the outside round bracket operation in calling the instances of UniqueDispatch? Thanks! Accepted Answer!

Comment: folding expression with comma operator.